# Laravel with dockerized nginx php-fpm showing 404 for uploaded media

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

We really need help for the problem to improve our current system (moving to docker).

After the build, the webapp is working fine, from login, managing resources (CRUD), uploading files, sending push notification and all.

But, the only problem is that, **when trying to access the the uploaded file, the app is throwing `404` (Laravel 404 page).**

We have tried the following:

- Run symlink command - `php artisan storage:link`
- Run optimize clear - `php artisan optimize:clear`

What we have noticed is that:

- the files are uploaded successfully to the `php` container which has its volume with the host

We have the following different docker-compose for `local`, `dev` & `prod` (nearly same as `dev`).

Below is the `docker-compose.dev.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/nginx:${IMAGE_TAG}
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -fsI http://localhost/login || exit 1
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 30s
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 10
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    image: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/php:${IMAGE_TAG}
    volumes:
      - storage:/var/www/html/storage
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 5
      update_config:
        order: start-first
    depends_on:
      - horizon

#..truncated as these are all working

volumes:
  db_data:
  db_log_data:
  redis_data:
  storage:
```

Below is the `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";


    client_body_buffer_size 16k;
    client_max_body_size 500k;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_body_timeout 15;
    client_header_timeout 15;

    keepalive_timeout 60;
    send_timeout 20;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    add_header Vary Accept=Encoding;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_types
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/xml
        text/x-component
        text/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/manifest+json
        application/xml
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/rss+xml
        application/atom+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-font-opentype
        application/x-font-truetype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        image/vnd.microsoft.icon
        font/ttf
        font/eot
        font/otf
        font/opentype;
    
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name {DOMAIN} {DOMAIN2};

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }    

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        index index.php index.html;
        server_name {DOMAIN} {DOMAIN2};
        root /var/www/html/public;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{DOMAIN}/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{DOMAIN}/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{DOMAIN}/chain.pem;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }   
}
```

Below is the `deploy.dockerfile` which is used when deploying to `dev` or `prod`.

```
FROM composer:1.10.22 as vendor
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY ./composer.json ./composer.lock* ./
COPY ./database ./database
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-interaction --no-plugins --no-scripts --prefer-dist

FROM node:12-buster as node_modules
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm install

FROM php:7.3-fpm as php

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev \
         libpq-dev libpng-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev libz-dev libxml2-dev \
         libreadline-dev libedit-dev libmagickwand-dev libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl

RUN docker-php-ext-install pgsql pdo pdo_mysql mysqli \
    gd imap mbstring xml zip bcmath soap \
    intl readline

RUN pecl install memcached xdebug msgpack igbinary imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached xdebug msgpack igbinary imagick

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl && \
    docker-php-ext-install pcntl

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY --from=vendor /var/www/html/vendor ./vendor
COPY --from=node_modules /var/www/html/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

CMD ["php-fpm"]

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as nginx
WORKDIR /var/www/html                #We tried commenting this out, no effect. 
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=php /var/www/html .      #We tried commenting this out, no effect.
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.